# Bootstrap's toggle button group not calling onChange event in react

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make use of bootstrap's toggle button group to select an option of platform. But the `onChange` event is not getting called.

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handlePlatformChange = this.handlePlatformChange.bind(this);
  }

  handlePlatformChange(event) {
    /* THIS DOES NOT GET CALLED */
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (<div className="container">
      <div className="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" onChange={this.handlePlatformChange} >
        <label className="btn btn-info active">
          <input type="radio" name="platform" value="web" autoComplete="off" /> Web
        </label>
        <label className="btn btn-info">
          <input type="radio" name="platform" value="android" autoComplete="off" /> Android
        </label>
        <label className="btn btn-info">
          <input type="radio" name="platform" value="ios" autoComplete="off" /> iOS
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My application is using webpack and below dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "query-string": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
  },
```

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s65x341L/) (by only including related libraries) to reproduce the issue.

```
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"popper.js": "^1.14.3",
"react": "^16.4.2",
"react-dom": "^16.4.2",
```

**Update-1:**

With the help from comments, I got the jsfiddle to work by using popper.js@1.14.3 instead of 1.14.4. I Also discovered that I had to import libraries in a specific order only. Working sample - https://codepen.io/hussaintamboli/pen/PdoVvG?editors=1111

How do I fix the order with webpack?

**Update-2:**

I created [this github repository](https://github.com/hussaintamboli/react-bootstrap-toggle-button-example) to reproduce the issue with react+bootstrap4+webpack4

Comment: @tarzenchugh that question uses jQuery, OP is asking for help with react-js

Comment: I guess that there is simply no change event emmited ;)

Comment: I tried an existing codepen with my code https://codepen.io/hussaintamboli/pen/PdoVvG?editors=1111. It seems to work here. Although I don't know what versions of libraries it is using.

Comment: @Hussain your pen uses bootstrap 3.3.7, this question is asking about bootstrap 4.1.3, maybe try changing version in your project if you can? Not an ideal solution.

Comment: I am actually not that familiar with codepen, How did you find that my pen is using different bootstrap? Can you please try with 4.1.3 and check if issue persists?

Comment: If you click on the settings icon, looks like a little cog next to CSS, it'll show you what libs you're using. I changed it to 4.1.2 and it was still working so maybe a problem with 4.1.3?

Comment: I did check on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#toggle-states and managed to add onChange listener to example overthere, and it works ;(

Comment: Just tried with 4.1.3 on codepen, seems like it works. Not sure what's causing this still.

Comment: Created a pen with same files from jsfiddle. https://codepen.io/hussaintamboli/pen/PdoVvG?editors=1111. Reproducing on codepen as well

Comment: @MichaelCurry It's strange if you remove popper.js and jquery from pen, it works.

Comment: `Popper.js1.14.4` looks like the culprit because event works with `1.14.3`

Comment: So it is not needed ?

Comment: Not sure. I installed it because my npm gives warnings to install it - `You must install peer dependencies yourself`

Comment: Thanks for the help @MichaelCurry. Do you think I should delete this question? I realise it's part my mistake because npm suggested I install popper@1.14.3 and jqeury@3.3.1 and I don't know why I installed popper@1.14.4.

Comment: Someone else may run into the issue. May be worth adding an answer explaining what the issue was and marking it as accepted in case somebody else does the same thing.

Comment: Don't know why I still can't get my jsfiddle to work with exact same code as pen and same libraries. https://jsfiddle.net/s2xcf6ya/1/

Comment: Seems like a problem with order of imports. Don't know how I can maintain order using webpack.

Comment: @Hussain that's a different question all together. I'd create a new question for that.

Comment: https://github.com/hussaintamboli/react-bootstrap-toggle-button-example to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#button-plugin)...

> "The checked state for these buttons is only updated via click event
>   on the button. "

Therefore, the *only* way to track (from Bootstrap JS) the changed button state is by clicking a button...

```
  handlePlatformChange(event) {
    var val = event.currentTarget.querySelector("input").value;
    this.setState({ currValue: val });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.currValue}</div>
        <div className="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label className="btn btn-info active" onClick={this.handlePlatformChange}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="platform"
              value="web"
              autoComplete="off"
            />{" "}
            Web
          </label>
          <label className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handlePlatformChange}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="platform"
              value="android"
              autoComplete="off"
            />{" "}
            Android
          </label>
          <label className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handlePlatformChange}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="platform"
              value="ios"
              autoComplete="off"
            />{" "}
            iOS
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/7kkqjy3lqx

Of course, once you get the relevant value (from the clicked button) you can always pass that off to some other handling logic.

Comment: Sounds fair. I overlooked it and because the codepen from my post is working with `onChange`, it made me believe `onChange` should work.

Comment: Life saving answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I thought at first that maybe the `div` element having the `onChange` on it was the issue since there wouldn't be any `change` event fired from the `div` no matter what components you click inside it, but even putting it onto the `input` elements wasn't fixing it.

I know it's not ideal, but putting an `onClick` event onto the `label` elements does work.

```
return (
  <div className="container">
    <div className="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" >
      <label className="btn btn-info active" onClick={this.handlePlatformChange} >
        <input type="radio" name="platform" value="web" autoComplete="off" /> Web
      </label>
      <label className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handlePlatformChange}>
        <input type="radio" name="platform" value="android" autoComplete="off" /> Android
      </label>
      <label className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handlePlatformChange}>
        <input type="radio" name="platform" value="ios" autoComplete="off" /> iOS
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`handlePlatformChange` will fire twice every time a button is clicked (once for the `<input>`, again for the `<label>`).

If you only want 1 event per click, you can check if the event has `checked` property.

```js
handlePlatformChange(event) {
  // <input> will have target.checked == true
  if (event.target.checked == null) return null;

  // handle your change here...
}
```

I got some React errors since I didn't have onChange for the `<input>`s and was setting the state from above, you can get rid of those by including `readOnly` -- `<input readOnly ... />`.